# Can I run Ubuntu 12.04 concurrently with Windows 7?

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot

I want to install Ubuntu on my laptop. Will i be able to install it without removing the windows 7 OS. I would like both of them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible , read this How to install :),

[How to Dual boot](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/dual-boot-windows-7-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse, you can install Ubuntu alongside Windows without losing any of your files or programs. During the installation of Ubuntu, the process provides you three options:

1. Install Ubuntu alongside Windows
2. Erase disk and install Ubuntu
3. Something else

The first option lets you to install Ubuntu parallel to your current OS. It won't disturb the existing OS and its programs. The second option erases your current OS and its programs and installs Ubuntu in its place but it will not harm the files that you have in some other partitions. The third option lets you to tasks like re-partitioning your hard disk.

In your case, you should choose the first option. For more information on installing Ubuntu (assuming that you are installing from a Live CD), visit https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall